# 2005 nissan altima alternator getting hot

Tags: electrical, nissan, alternator, altima

I have a 2005 Nissan Altima 2.5 liter.

The first issue is that my belt was vibrateing badly when I would run the air conditioning.  I came to find out it was a pulley on the alternator that was bad. You can't just replace component, you have to buy the whole alternator. Bought one from auto zone  on June 20th and buy end of July it went bad. It first smelt like a electrical wires burning but couldn't figure it out, the next day it was fine . Took it back to autozone  and had it checked it was good put it back on 2 days later wife was driving the car and it broke down. Some of the parts inside fell apart so I took it back and replaced it. When I put the new one on the alternator was getting hot Within 45 seconds to a minute.

Does anyone know what it is going on with it or is the heat a normal occurrence?

Comment: Check the wiring around the alternator, and from it all the way back to the battery for shorts or corroded connections, maybe?